# if ($(window).width() not working, ignores if condition on browser resize

Tags: jquery, window, width, slidetoggle

I have an (infamous) hamburger button that opens a dropdown on smaller devices. Since the slideToggle should only work on click if the viewport is less than 999px in width, my approach is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
        $("#mainNav a").click(function () {
            $("#mainNav").slideToggle(300);
        });
    }
});
```

This actually works like a charm, however, when resizing the window, from under 1000px width to above, the slideToggle also affects the 'regular desktop menu'.

I assume that I am using the wrong listener and already tried

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
```

but cannot make it work. I am pretty sure that the answer is near. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sub selector are written like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
        $("#mainNav").on('click','a',function() {
            $("#mainNav").slideToggle(300);

        });
    }


});
```

If you resize your window, make sure you reload webpage at each viewport. so that it actually show the real output.
**media queries can also be used. (Suggestion)**

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am using media queries, but I am not aware of a slideToggle equivalent in CSS, hence above approach. The issue maintains.

Comment: I don't see any problem , do you press refresh button after resizing your browser window? and yes there is no equivalent in css but alternative ways to do it like creating class and then adding it to the #mainNav using onClick event either by jquery or html

Comment: As hinted, it works perfectly if the browser is refreshed/reloaded. I would like to make it work without said steps (automagically). Is there a specific listener I could use?